# Evaluation order of the expressions

Tags: c, operator-precedence

The C Programming Language by K & R states that C, like most languages, does not specify the order in which operands of an operator are evaluated. (The exceptions are &&,||,?: and ','). According to the book, the result of the statement :

```
printf("%d %d\n",++x,power(2,x));
```

depends on the compiler. But it itself says in the previous line,that I have quoted that it does not predict the order of evaluation,except ',' and others. So don't you think book is contradicting itself?

Comment: I assume KKR was meant to be K & R?

Answer (score 5):

The first statement (the exceptions) refers to the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), this is (usually) different to commas in function calls.

The comma operator is used rarely, but can be used to do things like this:

```
int i,j; /* not comma operator */
for(i=0,j=0; i<10 && j<10; ++i, ++j) /* comma operators */
{ 
    doProcWith2Args(i,j); /*not comma operator*/
}
```

evaluation of operands of the comma operator is always left to right (it forms a sequence in standardese). Normal function parameter commas do not promise anything about their order of evaluation (and in general a program that changed depending on order of evaluation will be said to exhibit 'undefined behaviour').

I don't have my copy of K&R here but I suspect if you re-read the part with the knowledge of the comma operator it may make more sense.